# How to remove chapter number in front of appendices in toc

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters, appendices

I added appendices using \begin{appendices} \end{appendices}, but it shows a chapter number in front of the appendices in the table of contents (see photo). How do I remove this? [image]

Comment: You have two possibilities: 1) put yours appendix in the backmatter of your book; 2) use * option for your appendix: \chapter*{Appendix A}

Answer (score 0):

Just redefine the TOC entry when you start the appendix chapters after the `\appendix` command, e.g.,

```
\appendix
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{}  % in "{}" you can customize the number format etc -- or remove the numbering altogether
\chapter{my appendix chapter 1}
\chapter{my appendix chapter 2}
% etc
```

(Here, the  'appendices` environment is not necessary)